# docker-machine create error with gcloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-machine

I have two projects on google cloud. I have a VM running in one of the projects running docker swarm. In the other project I have another VM. In this VM I’ve authenticated gcloud with the other project. I’m trying to connect to the remote docker host in the other project from this VM but its failing. I get this error:

Error with pre-create check: “Project with ID “my-project-id” not found. googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions”

Here’s my docker-machine create command:

```
docker-machine create --driver google --google-address=IP address of VM --google-username=username --google-use-existing --google-project my-project-id dev
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: any updates on this one? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: It was solved by adding the gce credential json file and exporting in an environment variable

Comment: Yes it was solved for me. Stopped using docker-machine :) Too many problems